# How to use git to merge two non-git projects

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have two projects that initially come from a common ancestor that I don't have anymore. Each of them evolved on their side for a long time. Now, I would like to do a merge and I would like to use git to do this.

I created this repository:

```
 *   Project A [BranchA]
 | * Project B [BranchB]
 |/ 
 * Initial init (Project A)
```

At first I want to identify the files that differ:

```
 git checkout BranchA
 git diff --stat BranchB
```

I can easily perform a manual merge from BranchB into BranchA by doing

```
 git difftool BranchA
```

and saving the modifications on the right file. However I sometime want to modify both files from BranchA and BranchB. For instance If I notice a variable name change on BranchA I can just stop the merge, replace the variable name in BranchB, commit the changes on BranchB and continue the manual merge.

At this point I will get lost because I interrupted the merge and I didn't keep any trace of which file I was working on. The `git diff --stat BranchB` won't help me because even if I successfully imported the changes from BranchB to BranchA, it will still remain some differences.

It is worth mentioning that I cannot use `git merge` because there is no common ancestor available on git because I imported two very different projects on an empty git repository. In this case `git merge` will do a very bad job. So I am looking for a better solution in order to:

1. Use a difftool to browse each file from both branches, push and get the differences until both files are identical.
2. Use git to keep trace of my changes and help me roll back to a previous version if I need to.
3. Use git to track the merge process with `git diff --stat`.

The only solution I've found is to init a bare repository in which I have BranchA and BranchB. I then clone it into two local directories. Each of them is pointing on a different branch.

```
                              +-->[ ]<--+ Bare repository
                              |         |
                    Branch A [ ]       [ ] Branch B
                              |         |
                              +->diff<--+
```

From this I can use my favorite merge/diff tool to manually modify my files on both branches. I can `commit`, `push`, `pull` my work whenever I want to.

However I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: To clarify: you say you don't have a common ancestor anymore, but do you truly have *no* common ancestor, or is this more a case of having a common "ancient" ancestor, with a large gap between that ancestor and the first commit in your two projects?

Comment: @WillPalmer Good point. I truly have a common ancestor but it is so old that I was hoping to forget it. Moreover, the project is hosted on ClearCase which is incredibly slow. It is possible to extract then import both branches + the common ancestor to git.

Comment: My recommendation would be to attempt to merge via the common ancestor. Would you like an answer detailing the steps involved in setting up that kind of merge? ("reparenting")

Comment: @WillPalmer I think the answers below will already help me a lot to  do the merge. I still have to choose the best answer. Where I am still confuse is how to do the premerge or stop the merge to switch back to a premerge state where I currently use `git diff --stat branchb` as a guide to reduce the amount of differences. The way I do the process is particularly painful especially if I have to also manage the common ancestor. My steps are: 1. identify a difference, 2. checkout A, 3. global replace of the difference, 4. checkout A, 5. Go back to (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to preserve the history of both projects A & B, as much as possible?

If not, I would suggest the following approach:

- create a repo, and an initial empty commit.
- in addition to master, create two branches off the initial commit: A and B
- Put a snapshot of projects A and B into each respective branch.

At this point, use the existing tools you know how to use in order to find identical parts of both branches, and commit the identical parts to master. Then, you should be able to rebase both branches A and B onto the new commit on master.

Lather, rinse, repeat, and continue taking chunks of identical code from A and B, putting them into master, and rebasing on them. You can do this in small, incremental steps.

At each step of the way you should have a single commit on both A and B branch, that's forked off the master branch.

At some point you will reach the step where you need to look at the differences. Let's take the hypothetical situation of different names for the same variables on branches A and B.

Well, rename the variable on one branch to the other branch's name, and rebase-squash that, so you still have a single commit on the A and B branch. This should end up with more code becoming identical on both branches, which you can pull out, commit on master, then rebase both A and B branches on top of it.

When you reach the point when there's nothing common between A and B, with both of them being one commit away from master, and none of them changing the parts that overlap, then you should be able to merge one branch into the other; with maybe some minor conflict resolution.

At each step in this process, your changes should be fairly small, and you wouldn't need to use a complicated diff or merge tool to work through it.

I would also suggest that after you commit what you think is a common chunk of code to master, and trying to rebase both A and B on top of the master's new commit, tag both branches A and B, and if either one of them fails, you can restore the other branch's tip to the previous tag, get rid of the new commit on master, and then try again.

Another refinement on this process would be that instead of using two branches+master, after creating the initial repo, clone the repo directory twice, then use the two new repos as, essentially branches: after isolating identical code, commit that chunk to the parent repo, re-pull the parent repo in the children, and try to rebase the branches in the child repos.

Comment: Can you provide some example about rebasing. I'm not familiar with this git feature. How to use the rebase in this particular case?

Comment: A rebase reapplies commits onto another git branch, or commit. A Google search of "git rebase" will bring back tons of more information that can be included in a brief comment. But, say you make branch A off master, with 1 more commit, then you made another commit, in parallel, on master. If you're back on branch A, "git rebase HEAD^ --onto master" would try to apply the last commit on top of the latest commit on master, which is the approach my answer is based off. There are various details concerning what happens if there's a conflict, that you need to learn, so you should practice, first.

Comment: ... continued. My mention of 'rebase-squash' refers to an interactive git rebase where you have an option to "squash" commits, that is, take two or more commits and replace them with a single combined commit. It's one of the options in an interactive git rebase. Based on your question I assumed that you were familiar with the rebase procedure, and proposed a way to use git rebase to do what you're trying to do. So, sounds to me like you'll need to brush up on it first, and understand how it works, before trying to merge the two projects in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your initial commit to the repository is a copy of project A, which you've then branched from and on the branch replaced with B.  Did you try making the parent commit just an empty commit?  I think this would give git a better chance of correctly merging, as it's not then assuming that all the changes in project B are as a result of edits to project A.  So your git tree would look like this:

```
*   A
| * B
|/
*   Initial Commit (empty)
```

With the magic of rebasing, you might even be able to start to put some genuinely common code into the parent, which might help too.

Comment: It's a very interesting point. But How can I pause the merge process and keep trace of where I was, how many files I've merged and how many files are unmerged?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest something close to [Sam's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27878801/86072) to re-build a history which displays more clearly what is common to A and B.

For the sole purpose of "pausing a manual merge, applying a patch to B, and resume the manual merge" however, [git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) looks like the tool you need :

1. start using `git difftool` as you mentioned
2. when hitting some you want to apply to both A and B, save your current changes in the stash :

   ```
   git stash
   ```
3. go to `BranchB`, apply your changes :

   ```
   git checkout BranchB
   # do whatever you want
   git add / git commit
   ```
4. return to `BranchA`

   ```
   git checkout BranchA
   ```
5. retrieve your changes from the stash

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```
6. `git difftool BranchB` ...